# Tensorflow < 2.4 chip M1

Tags: python, tensorflow, apple-m1, tensorflow2.x

I am working on a project which requirements need python `3.7` and TensorFlow `2.3.1`. The problem, I have a MacBook Pro with `M1 chip`. I was able to install and run TF `2.4`.

However, I am running into more complicated compatibility issues.

Does anyone know how can I solve this?

Comment: Does this comment helps https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/44751#issuecomment-764841687

Answer (score 3, accepted):

M1 has a compatibility issue with TensorFlow. There is a workaround provided by Apple and other blogs. I have recently tried the same and have provided the summary below:

Tensorflow:
OS: `BigSur(11.2.3)`

**Install command-line tools:**

- `xcode-select --install`

**Install miniforge:**

- https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge#miniforge3

After download run

1. `chmod +x ~/<dir>/Miniforge3-MacOSX-arm64.sh`
2. `sh ~/<dir>/Miniforge3-MacOSX-arm64.sh`

`dir`: directory to which miniforge is downloaded.

Or

1. `brew install miniforge`
2. After download change source to miniforge3
3. `source ~/miniforge3/bin/activate`

Download the `environment.yml` file from
https://github.com/mwidjaja1/DSOnMacARM

**Setup a new conda environment using the yml file:**

- `conda env create --file=environment.yml --name env_name`
- conda activate env_name

**Install tensorflow dependencies:**

- `conda install -c apple tensorflow-deps`

**Install base tensorflow:**

- `python -m pip install tensorflow-macos`

**Install tensorflow-metal plugin:**

- `python -m pip install tensorflow-metal`

**Possible Issues:**

- Miniforge uses `conda-forge` to install packages
- Method to route channel to `conda-forge`
- `conda install -c conda-forge matplotlib`
- `conda install` or `pip install` might not work

**Packages available for libraries in conda-forge:**

https://anaconda.org/conda-forge

Only these will work.

**Sources:**

- https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/
- https://towardsdatascience.com/installing-tensorflow-on-the-m1-mac-410bb36b776
- https://github.com/mwidjaja1/DSOnMacARM

Comment: This doesn't meet the OP requirement of using  python3.7